# Why is an "empty" Gradle build so slow?

Tags: gradle

Is it normal for Gradle to take 3-4 seconds to run a task like this (with nothing else added to the build file)?

```
task testtask {

    doFirst{
        println 'test1'
    }
}
```

This is *after* the "starting Gradle Daemon" run to make builds "faster".  Isn't that a little ridiculous? Or is my environment just terrible and it shouldn't be that slow? (Any way to speed things up?)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you start any task, Gradle reparses the script for changes and correctness. Actual task execution happens after that. 4 seconds doesn't seem unusual to me.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that debug logging is enabled and has triggered the execution of extra, time-consuming metrics-collection activities. See [this other Stack Overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021142/why-is-gradle-build-of-kotlin-source-code-pausing-for-3-secs-forcing-system-gc) for more info.

Otherwise, enable Gradle profiling to help narrow down what the culprit is. *(eg. `gradle --profile build`)*