# Why is Gradle build of Kotlin source code pausing for ~3 secs "forcing System.gc()"?

Tags: performance, gradle, garbage-collection, kotlin

Every build takes an extra 3-4 seconds, pausing immediately after the log output prints the following.

> [LIFECYCLE]
>   [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices] Forcing
>   System.gc()

Why is it "forcing" this? How do I avoid this and speed up my build?

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this, and this is a consequence of having Gradle's debug-level logging enabled *(eg. `gradle --debug assemble`)*.

Run Gradle without debug logging enabled *(eg. `gradle --info assemble`)* and this should not occur anymore.

References: [libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinGradleBuildServices.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/e25060f8c9fd447ee22b0d6def9940ab4ff5a6a9/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinGradleBuildServices.kt#L166)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Gradle plugins calls `System.gc` before and after a build only when debug logging is enabled (Gradle is run with `-d` or `--debug` command line argument).
Users do not normally run Gradle with debug logging enabled because it is extremely noisy and slow, so forcing a GC is a relatively minor issue.

Historically this behaviour was added to test against memory leaks when Gradle daemon is enabled. The idea was to log a difference of used memory before and after a build, run a few builds consequently in a test, and assert that the difference is not exceeding the threshold.

I think calling `System.gc` should be avoided unless the test `KotlinGradleIT#testKotlinOnlyDaemonMemory` is running, so I've created an issue at Kotlin bugtracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17960

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a way in which they could achieve their debugging goals that doesn't bog down new Gradle users such as myself. Given that builds can be lengthy and that oftentimes the only way to find out why Gradle is making the decisions it makes is with `--debug`, I've been dumping its output to disk and relying on it quite heavily for now. If they agree that they can live without memory diagnostics running on every user build, I'd be 3 seconds happier. (voted for the YouTrack issue)